# Function working in browser, "undefined or private" in controller tests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am currently trying to convert my main Rails application to Phoenix for learning purposes.

I have a pretty standard Phoenix 1.3.0 application (running under Elixir 1.5.2) in which I am trying to set the CSS class of my layout's `<body>` element. How I do that does not really matter, so let's assume this function just looks like this:

```js
def body_class(conn) do
  "some-class"
end
```

When I put this function in the `lib/my_app_web/views/layout_view.ex` file, it works as expected (in the browser as well as when running `mix test`).

Then I tried to extract this function into a module (called `PageTitle`). However, no matter where I reference this module with `import MyAppWeb.PageTitle` (I do not know where to correctly put the corresponding file so I tried `lib/my_app_web/page_title.ex` and `lib/my_app_web/views/page_title.ex`), it **works in the browser** but not when I run `mix test`.

I also tried to put the `import` call in the `controller` and `view` section of my app's `my_app_web.ex` file (so that it is included via Phoenix' `use` macro in controllers) but to no avail.

Controller tests always fail with this:

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyAppWeb.PageTitle.body_class/1 is undefined or private`

I assume the `Phoenix.ConnTest.get/2` function Phoenix uses in controller tests works in a different way than requesting a page in the browser.

Unfortunately I haven't yet grasped Phoenix so I could not find any hints what I am doing wrong.

(I have changed file and module names for this question — my real application is named differently — but as everything works as expected when running in a browser, you can act on the assumption that there is no problem with file filenames or typos therein.)

I appreciate comments on whether or not this is the Phoenix-way of centrally setting body classes but my main question is: How can I make this work in tests as well as in the real app (and what am I doing wrong so that it does not work)?

Comment: Why would you even need to [`import MyAppWeb.PageTitle`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import)? Call `MyAppWeb.PageTitle.body_class(conn)` explicitly, it’s always better than polluting local namespace.

Comment: I think I started using `import MyAppWeb.PageTitle` because of this issue — calling `MyAppWeb.PageTitle.body_class(@conn)` from `app.html.eex` without importing the module also yields `** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyAppWeb.PageTitle.body_class/1 is undefined or private`.

Comment: This issue is way easier to debug. This should not happen, and we should understand why it indeed happens. Would you mind to try running `iex -S mix phx.server` and then call the suspect explicitly from the console?

Comment: Ah! Please try to move the helper outside of your `_web` folder and put it into, say, `lib/my_app/helpers/page_title.ex`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Same issue. I decided to create a new Phoenix app from scratch and implement the PageTitle module there. Interestingly, everything works as expected in the new app — so I guess I'll have to track down the differences now …